# Form confirmation ValidationError for similar objects

Tags: django, django-forms

Before saving an object, I'd like to add a validation warning message to ask the end user whether he/she does want to continue or not, given similar data returned from the database.

For example, when the end user is adding a `Hospital`, and one or more `Hospital` objects already exists in that `zipcode`, then a `ValidationError` should be provided saying something like `Following hospitals in zipcode XX were already found: YYY, ZZZZ. Hit submit again to save if you're sure you want to add another one.`

I tried to achieve this using the below form, by adding a field `Verified` (set as `HiddenInput`). It seems though I cannot modify the field.

```
class CreateHospitalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    verified = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
        verified = cleaned_data.get('verified')

        existing_hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(zipcode=zipcode)

        if existing_hospitals and not verified:
            cleaned_data['verified'] = True  # <<< here I'd like to set verified to True so I don't get the below warning a 2nd time when saving the form
            raise ValidationError(u"Following hospitals already exist in this zipcode: " + ', '.join([str(x) for x in existing_hospitals] + ". Are you sure you want to add another one? Then hit submit again.")

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
        fields = ('name', 'street_and_number', 'zipcode', 'town', 'country', 'email', 'web', 'comments', 'verified')
```

Any idea how to get around this issue?
Using Django 1.7.

**EDIT**: My view is very standard and goes below, as requested:

```
class CreateHospitalView(generic.CreateView):

    model = Hospital
    template_name = 'hosp_add.html'
    form_class = CreateHospitalForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('hosp_detail', args=(self.object.id,))
```

Comment: Your form looks good, this can be solved in your view. Show us what you got.

Comment: As a sidenote, I think the better approach here (instead of reloading the whole page) is to make an ajax request when the user fills the form, check for existing hospitals and, if needed, display a warning message.

Comment: @danielcorreia: I've added my view (very standard). Agreed that AJAX is probably a better way, I'll look into that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your answer. Update your clean method to this (see comments in code).

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    zipcode = cleaned_data.get('zipcode')
    verified = cleaned_data.get('verified')

    existing_hospitals = Hospital.objects.filter(zipcode=zipcode)

    if existing_hospitals and not verified:
        self.data = self.data.copy()  # self.data is immutable, so we make a copy to get around this
        self.data['verified'] = True  # instead of self.cleaned_data['verified'] = True
        raise ValidationError(u"Following hospitals already exist in this zipcode: " + ', '.join([str(x) for x in existing_hospitals] + ". Are you sure you want to add another one? Then hit submit again.")

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks! FYI for anyone else: I had to add `required=False` to `verified = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)`. Changed opening post.